# Does HttpContext.Session in ASP.NET Core share session data between users?

Tags: asp.net-core, session, session-state

We have an ASP.NET core application which stores objects from a user's session to record values before the information is added to the database.

We have an issue where two different users (on opposites side of the world) are able to influence one another's session and we can't understand why?

*For example if User1 has a session variable set, the same value influences User2's session.*

I have read previously that `AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext.Session` is unique per user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293432/)  however the post is confusing and the answers contradict what Microsoft says.

Should I really be using `HttpContext.Session` to store data which should be unique at user-level and if not what should I use?

Comment: It is impossible to say from the level of information you are providing, but if I had to guess, I'd say that the code that deals with persisting the session to the database has a bug in it.

Comment: do you have any custom back store for your session? A `MemoryDistributedCache` (default implementation for back store of session in asp.net core) should not have that issue.

Comment: Check the [latest version document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#session-state): *Don't store sensitive data in session state. The user might not close the browser and clear the session cookie. Some browsers maintain valid session cookies across browser windows. A session might not be restricted to a single user. The next user might continue to browse the app with the same session cookie.*